# Cognito Forgot password fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've Created a user using admin create user. The user was able to change the temporary password and login into the application. But, when the user tried forgot the password, and type an email Cognito throws an error

```
Could not reset the password for the account, please contact support or try again
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, by setting

```
email_verified: true
```

in the User attribute list.